# Blender doesnt render any shadow

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I´ve been looking for a solution online for this everywhere can´t seem to find anything. My issue is that I have the scene displayed on the image, and there are no shadows rendered on it. Don´t know what I touched on or off for this to happen. Any ideas?[image: blen]

Comment: please show us your .blend file

Comment: https://we.tl/t-2DWwxtZsvK

Hi Chris, I used some toon shader (or an attempt of that) on some elements, but even with no material applied they don´t cast any shadows on themselves or other objects

Answer (score 1):

1. Your lights are de-activated in the viewport - No light, no shadow (click the eye icon)
2. Emission shaders don't receive shadows
3. If you plug a color into the output of a shader, it is automatically converted to an emission shader. Try with a principled bsdf or a diffuse shader
4. Your scene is not up-to-scale. Your couch is 3 meters high and 9 meters wide. The lighting won't be realistic if you don't try to respect realistic proportions
5. Turn way up the power of your point light

[image]

If you want a cartoony look you can use the "Shader to RGB" node after the shader. Also use ambient occlusion to add to the realism

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are awesome! That proportions thing fixed everything...Thanks a lot!